# Specify col_type by name in lapply

Tags: r, multiple-columns, lapply, numeric

I am reading in multiple files into R from Excel using `lapply`. I have just noticed that some of my files are having the `data` column being read in as a `logical` and not `numeric`.

I would like to use the `col_types` argument of `read_xls`, but my files have different numbers of columns so would like to call them by name.

Any idea how I can do this?
This is how I am importing the data at the moment:

```
file_list=list.files(file_location, pattern="^ID.*xls",full.names = T) 
import=lapply(file_list, function(x) read_xls(x, col_names = T))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may define a list containing the various `col_type` vectors you intend to apply to each incoming Excel file.  Then, use `lapply` with an index, to access those formatting vectors:

```
cols <- list(c("logical", "numeric", "text"), c("logical", "numeric"))

lapply(seq_along(file_list), function(y, n, i) {
    read_xls(x, col_names=TRUE, col_types=cols[[i]])
}, y=file_list, n=names(file_list))
```

Follow the link below for a small demo showing that the basic premise should work.

### Demo

Comment: Thanks - made some minor adjustments to get it working, but has done exactly what i want.